# How to refresh a current form in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am creating a multiple form windows application using C#, I have two form one Parent form and a child form.

From parent form I called the child form to add a tree node in the parent form treeview. After entering the details in the child form and pressing "Add" button I want to close the child form and want to add the tree node in the treeview dynamically inside the parent form.

The value is passing perfect, I am using properties for the transfer. Rest by using this.Show() another parent form opens up. I have already tried Invalidate() and Refresh() but the treeview does not get updated.

Comment: Normally, one does not need to invalidate the control: it invalidates itself. Are you absolutely sure (no offense) that the data is finally updated in the treeview (you could for instance try to obtain data from the treeview itself)?

Comment: I'm confused.  Where's the code?  What's the problem?  Why are you using multiple forms for this?  What is the bigger picture of what you're trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override child form constructor to accept parent form as parameter

`ChiildForm chilForm=new ChildForm(parentFormObject);`

Now you can call method of parent form that would make the required change on the page.

```
parentFormObject.RefreshSection();
```

Answer (score 1):

> but the treeview does not get updated

To refresh the treeview you need to rebind it to your datasource after adding the newly added item of child form.

**Example**:

```
List<SomeClass> items = new List<SomeClass>();
if(childForm.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Ok)
{
   items.Add(childForm.newlyAddedItem); //you have mentioned that values are passing perfect
   //your code for rebinding to the treeview
}
```

Comment: if you are using show, then you need to fire an event that is registered on the main form. Though in my opinion you need to use ShowDialog instead of show.

Comment: it is just an example of how you should do it.

Answer (score 1):

---

If you want to refresh after clicking Add buttons,
just try to call the load_ function by sending the parameters.
example,

```
button_click(Object sender,Event_args e)
{
 Form_Load(sender,e);
}
```

---